# Github Desktop not fit in the screen windows

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I just installed GitHub desktop on my Windows 10 64bit. The software functions OK but the window of it won't fit in the window. Once I click on maximize button, the right side of the window just go out of the screen. Here is a screen shot, how can I fix it?
[image]
Thanks a lot for your help!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move / resize your window using only your keyboard.

Type Alt+Space Bar and then resize or move the window using the pointers that appear.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too - the window wasn't resizeable and I was unable to reach some parts with my mouse. It turned out that my PC caused this problem when returning from energy saving mode. After I restarted my PC Gihub Desktop worked fine again. This problem can happen especially when using a laptop with an external monitor over HDMI. Then some Apps seem not to recognize the monitors resolution and takes the resolution of the laptop instead. So it's mostly a Windows issue.

Answer (score 2):

This should still be an issue. Here is my simple solution.

- Remove the following file. ('user' in my case, yours could be different.)

  `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\GitHub Desktop\window-state.json`
- Restart GitHub Desktop.

<><

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i solved it by click to the **Alt** button

now you can see the topBar and you can resize it

and you can use **Alt + Space**